# Dependency problem for pdftk

Tags: dependencies

Under Ubuntu 11.04, when I try to install pdftk via apt-get or synaptic, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pdftk : Depends: libgcj-bc (< 4.6~) but 4.6.0-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I know pdftk works just fine on Ubuntu on previous versions. How can I fix the dependencies so that I can now install pdftk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my 11.04, `libgcj-bc` is version 4.5.2-1, which would satisfy the dependencies. This probably means that you have caught a newer version by a PPA, backports, or other means. Open synaptic, select `libgcj-bc`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and select a version lower than 4.6.

This should solve the installation of `pdf-tk` but may introduce other dependency problems, which could be addressed by removing the dependent packages and install the distribution releases. Yet it may be wiser to await 11.10 where more recent packages are available.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I never knew that the older packages were still available, is this possible from the command line apt-get as well?

Comment: Yes, you could have achieved this with `apt-get install libgcj-bc=4.5.2-1ubuntu3`. No idea how to get available versions, though.